# Make angular reevaluate complete page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, digest

we recently switched to Angular 1.3.x and now noticed that it seems to perform much better dirty checking. However there is a case (changing the language for the complete site) where our old implementation expects a reevaluation of certain expressions. This doesn't work anymore. What we would need is to somehow reset angular's dirty checking to make it reevaluate all expressions at least once. Is there a way to do this?
$scope or $rootScope.apply() obviously does not work.

**UPDATE for clarification:**
We have created our own i18n filter, which uses a service to get appropriate translations. It can be used like:

```
{{'MyString'|i18n}}
```

If we change the language, it will cause the service to use different a translation package. However we change the language somewhere in our SPA and since the expression is just a string it will never change, thus it will not be evaluated, translated and re-rendered. Honestly, now that I think about it, I don't know how it ever worked with Angular 1.2.

BR,
Daniel

Comment: Can you give an example of an expression that is not dirty checking?  What version of Angular are you migrating from?

Comment: what does "expect reevaluation of certain expressions" mean? Anytime a $watched expression changes its value Angular catches it.

Comment: I hope you doesnt use {{:: something}} notation. That is binding "once".

Comment: added update for clarification